# mail непонятный символы в письме

Tags: php, email

При отправке почты получаю в тексте письма :" раÐ! �мещение в информациоÐ �ной системе протоко..." подобное , текст в письмо структурирую с помошью foreach.. то есть беру с массива. Отправляю следующим образом :

```
$message = "<html><body>";
 $message .= "<h3 style='text-align:center'>Поздравляем bla .</h3>";
 $message .= "<h2 style='text-align:center;'>Ответы</h2>";
    foreach ($err_array as $err => $el) {
         foreach ($el as $item => $val) {
      $message .= '<h4>Вопрос №'. $err .'</h4>';
           $val = htmlentities($errors_to_send[$err]['otvet']);
     $message .= '<h4>'.$my_questions[$err]['quest']. '</h4>';
     $message .= '<p>Правильный ответ:'. htmlentities($my_questions[$err]['answers'][--$val]) .'</p>';
     $message .= '<h5>Комментарий :</h5><p>' . htmlentities($errors_to_send[$err]['comment']) .'</p><hr>';
     }
 }
$messahe .= "</body></html>"
$subject = 'Ответы на тест.';

$headers = "From: admin@bla-bla.ru\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To:  admin@bla-bla.ru\r\n";
$headers .= "CC:  admin@bla-bla.ru\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
//ISO-8859-1 попробуем явно указать utf-8 
//$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

if(mail($_POST["mail"],$subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo "<p>Письмо отправлено на почту </p>".$_POST["mail"];
}else echo "<p>mail to ".$_POST["mail"]." return false.";
```

Comment: если посмотреть на тело письма , которое пришло на почту ... "Bom символ" появляется циклически - через  ~ каждые четыре строки ... и не совпадает с foreach которым я вставляю инфу ..

Answer (score 1):

(сомнительно что вопрос актуален автору и получится проверить гипотезу, но тем не менее)

Посмотрите в raw виде само приходящее письмо со всеми заголовками. В почтовом клиенте должна быть возможность показа исходного пришедшего письма.

Моё внимание цепляется за то, что вы весь документ письма собираете в одну длинную строку. Не в том смысле что в php string, а в том смысле что без символов перевода строки. Это нормально для веба и html, однако не нормально для куда более старой электронной почтой. В частности, одна строка тела письма [не может превышать 998 байт](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821).

```
text line

The maximum total length of a text line including the
<CRLF> is 1000 characters (but not counting the leading
dot duplicated for transparency).
```

При том эти разрывы строк может вставлять самостоятельно ваш либо промежуточные почтовые сервера, ломая при этом многобайтовые символы.

Функция `mail` - очень низкоуровневая штука, (наивно) предполагающая, что вызывающий её код оформит всё письмо корректно самостоятельно. Лучше использовать какую-либо библиотеку поверх вызова `mail`, которая возьмёт на себя вопросы представления текста и формирования корректных заголовков. Например, [`PHPMailer`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно кодировка вашего скрипта не UTF-8. Используйте функцию [mb_internal_encoding](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-internal-encoding.php) в самом начале скрипта с установкой на UTF-8, либо проверьте чтобы PHP файл был в этой кодировке.

Comment: Сомнительно. Тогда бы вообще всё испортилось, а у него в произвольных местах битые символы.

Comment: на файл - значения массива . я тоже часа 2 назад думал..но нет  - явно не в нем дело, а message - тело письма - можно указывать заголовок. <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional //EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: Добавьте код чтобы можно было сделать http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример)

Comment: воспроизвести пример можно  на домене ... seminar-starsof.app-labs.ru
в форме тест .. проходите тест - вводите почту .. получаете ошибки на почту

Comment: Но мы же не увидим код этого минимального и воспроизводимого примера чтобы судить что именно в нем не так.

Answer (score 0):

```
encodeURIComponent("Ð �")
"%C3%90%20%EF%BF%BD"
encodeURIComponent("н")
"%D0%BD"
```

Пробел `%20` лишний, последний байт совпадает `%BD`. `%EF%BF` смахивает на мусор.

Скорее всего ты где-то разбиваешь строку в UTF8 между байтами (возможно, вставкой этого самого пробела; либо просто где-то происходит считывание не в байтовый буфер, а в строковый с немедленным конвертированием), после чего предпринимается автоматическая попытка восстановить битую строку до читаемого состояния.

Comment: Пробовал заменить весь текст .. в массиве - ответа  - не помогло .. такое ощущение . что символы появляются рандомно ..